# Javascript Unlock button in HTML and database issue

Tags: javascript, html

This is my html code, when ever someone clicks this question he should be able to unlock the other questions based on the ans he gave to this question

```
<div class="section"><span>2</span>See more questions</div>
        <label for="chkYes">
                  <input name="Q2" id="Q2Yes"  type="radio" value="Yes" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" />Yes </label>
         <label for="chkNo">
                   <input name="Q2" id="Q2No"  type="radio" value="No" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" />No</label>
```

The javascript Function:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
       function ShowHideDiv() {
           var chkYes = document.getElementById("Q2Yes");
           var dvPassport = document.getElementById("dvPassport");
           dvPassport.style.display = chkYes.checked ? "block" : "none";
    }
</script>
```

The problem I am getting is when ever I save the data that the user inputs I am getting the answer for the question as "On" instead of Yes or No.
Can anyone suggest me what to do?

Comment: to get Yes use - `chkYes.value`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the tag itself. You need to use:

```
var chkYes = document.getElementById("Q2Yes").value; // "Yes"
```